# ElasticSearch defining sorting

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, groovy

I have a local sorting on the client.

```
class Comp implements Comparator<String> {      
       @Override
       public int compare(String obj1, String obj2) {
        …
        …
             return -1;
       }
}
```

How can it be transferred to ElastichSearch ? I understand it will be necessary to write a script on Groovy. The question is, what about the parameters in the query ?

```
GET /_search
{
    "script_fields": {
        "my_field": {
            "inline": "1 + my_var",
            "params": {
              "my_var": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could you help me with that? This is my first experience with NoSQL databases.

Comment: Why do you want to order using scripts? Look at [Sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting.html)

Comment: Based on your question it's obvious you aren't reading the documentation. If you're new then NoSql in general and ElasticSearch then I would recommend taking a step back and taking time to learn the fundamental concepts. Read the documentation and play around with [Sense](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig?hl=en)

Comment: Just do not know how to do it right and better. If after a request, I do not understand how to translate the query, a class with private methods and its logic.

Comment: I write small plugin and stuck
How to compare rows on elastic?

How to realize compare on elastic or should we do differently ?